# Create a Gradle function for dependencies block in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin, gradle, groovy, gradle-plugin

Currently, I'm creating a function, which is available for the `dependencies` block in Groovy with:

```
project.dependencies.ext.foo = { String value ->
    project.files(extension.getFooDependency(project).jarFiles).asFileTree
}
```

Thanks to that, I'm able to do:

```
afterEvaluate {
    dependencies {
        compileOnly foo('junit')
    } 
}
```

I'm converting the Groovy code to Kotlin, and I'm wondering how to rewrite this `foo` extension.
I've ended up with:

```kotlin
project.dependencies.extensions.extraProperties.set("foo", Action { value: String ->
    project.files(extension.getIdeaDependency(project).jarFiles).asFileTree
})
```

After calling `foo('junit')`, I get the following exception:

```
> Could not find method foo() for arguments [junit] on object of type org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not think that would work the same way in Kotlin DSL. Instead, you may declare a Kotlin extension function somewhere in the project. Then calling it would include all necessary receivers to you.

For multiple projects, I would recommend using a `buildSrc` project. Declarations there are visible to all project files below.

Speaking about Groovy and Kotlin support, I would do something like that:

```
private fun getFooImpl(scope: getFooImpl, name: String) { /*here is the implementation */ }

fun DependencyHandlerScope.getFoo(name:String) = getFooImpl(this, name)

//in Groovy
project.dependencies.extensions.extraProperties.set("foo", {getFooImpl(..)})
```

The same code could fit into a plugin as well. A more generic way could be to register a [custom DLS extension](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/custom_plugins.html#sec:getting_input_from_the_build), so to allow a custom block-like `thisIsMyPlugin { .. }` in the Gradle DSL and define all necessary helper functions in the extension class. Here the downside is in forcing users to wrap their code into the `thisIsMyPlugin` block.